# struts 2 doesnt do division when value is a double?

Tags: struts2

I have a very weird scenario in struts2.

When I do the following:

```
<s:property value="%{4/2}"/>
```

I get 2.

But when I do the following:

```
<s:property value="%{2/4}"/>
```

I get  a big fat 0.

the property tag is always outputting an Integer even when the evaluated value is a double.  How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing integer arithmetic because your inputs are integers, not doubles: two divided by four **is** zero for integers.  Try this:

```
<s:property value="%{2.0/4.0}"/>
```

instead.

Comment: damn. that was a 'dumb' moment